# Remove an Object and add another in TreeSet

Tags: java, list, object, treeset, sortedset

I am working with Tree Set in java to add some objects in the set . Each object is a signal with different properties. Everytime a new signal comes I set some attributes of the object (Signal) and add it to the set, A signal can come more then one time. For signals I mantain a list in which I store the signal name and when I signal comes I check if the signal is in the list or not If it is not in the list I simply add a new object to my set but if the signal is in the list I take that signal from the set and modify some of its attributes , remove the signal and and add a new one.

The problem is that when I signal comes for the 2nd time or 3rd time and so on it does not remove the old signal and keep all the occurance of the same signal with modified attributes.

Here is my code

```
 SortedSet<Signal> set = new TreeSet<Signal>();

 ArrayList< String > messages = new ArrayList< String >();

   //If the Message is new one              
            if(!messages.contains(messageName)){
                //System.out.println("I am new signal");
                //Add the new Message in Message List 
                messages.add(messageName);

                //Create Object of Message to be stored in Set
                signal = new Signal();
                signal.setSource(messageSource);
                signal.setName(messageName);
                if(messageSource.equals("egdci") || messageSource.equals("ugdci"))
                    signal.setComponent(egdci_ugdci_msgComponent);
                else
                    signal.setComponent(messageComponent);
                signal.setOccurance(messageCounter);
                signal.setSize(messageContent.length);
                signal.setBandwidth(0F);

                //Add the new Message Object in the Set  
                set.add(signal);
            }            
            //If Message already exists in the list
            else{
                //System.out.println("I am old one");
                Iterator<Signal> iterator = set.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    signal = (Signal)iterator.next();
                    if(signal.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(messageName)){
                        System.out.println("I am here");
                        int occurance  = signal.getOccurance() + 1;
                        int size = occurance * messageContent.length;
                        float bandwidth  = 0F;                          
                        set.remove(signal);

                        signal = new Signal();
                        signal.setSource(messageSource);
                        signal.setName(messageName);
                        if(messageSource.equals("egdci") || messageSource.equals("ugdci"))
                            signal.setComponent(egdci_ugdci_msgComponent);
                        else
                            signal.setComponent(messageComponent);
                        signal.setOccurance(occurance);
                        signal.setSize(size);
                        signal.setBandwidth(bandwidth);

                        //Add the new Message Object in the Set  
                        set.add(signal);
                    }                           
                }
            }

     writeToCSV(signal , writer);
```

More over I try to sort my signals in the file on the basis of occurance of a signal, the higher the value of occurance, on the top it should be in the file.

Here is my code of compareTo in Signal.java (I am using Tree Set for the first time so Not sure how to implement my comapreTo)

```
    @Override
   public int compareTo(Signal signal) {
       int thisOccurance = this.getOccurance();
       return thisOccurance.compareTo(signal.getOccurance());
   }
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only remove the old signal, you can use remove it with:

```
iterator.remove();
```

Once the while ends you can create and then add your new Signal to the set.

You else condition should look like:

```
    else {
        // System.out.println("I am old one");
        final Iterator<Signal> iterator = set.iterator();
        boolean deleted = false;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            signal = (Signal)iterator.next();
            if(signal.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(messageName)){
                iterator.remove();
                deleted = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(delted){
            int occurance  = signal.getOccurance() + 1;
            int size = occurance * messageContent.length;
            float bandwidth  = 0F;              

            signal = new Signal();
            signal.setSource(messageSource);
            signal.setName(messageName);
            if(messageSource.equals("egdci") || messageSource.equals("ugdci"))
                signal.setComponent(egdci_ugdci_msgComponent);
            else
                signal.setComponent(messageComponent);
            signal.setOccurance(occurance);
            signal.setSize(size);
            signal.setBandwidth(bandwidth);

            //Add the new Message Object in the Set  
            set.add(signal);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my else condition I iterate over my set find the signal I am looking for and remove it from set is it not the correct way to do it ? Kindly have a look at my code

Comment: I read your code. There you are changing the set structure while you are itering over it, you should use the Iterator "remove" method to remove an element (and then if you prefer break the while). 
And once your while is finish you can add the new signal.